# cross platform build of numpy (host=x86 target=ppc) wrong compiler options generated?

Tags: python, numpy, x86, powerpc

I am trying to do a cross platform build of numpy (host=x86 target=ppc). This worked for python compiler itself but for numpy I run into 
following problem.

It does select the correct compiler but the options are not correct. please advise...

```
 numpy-1.10.2rc2]$ CC=powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnuspe-gcc CXX=powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnuspe-g++ AR=powerpc-e500v2-linux-
gnuspe-ar                            BLAS=None LAPACK=None ATLAS=None  python setup.py build  bdist_egg   --plat-name=powerpc


powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnuspe-gcc: _configtest.c
powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnuspe-gcc: error: unrecognized argument in option '-mtune=generic'
powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnuspe-gcc: note: valid arguments to '-mtune=' are: 401 403 405 405fp 440 440fp 464 464fp 476 476fp 505 601 
602 603 603e 604 604e 620 630 740 7400 7450 750 801 821 823 8540 8548 860 970 G3 G4 G5 a2 cell common e300c2 e300c3 e500mc 
e500mc64 ec603e native power power2 power3 power4 power5 power5+ power6 power6x power7 powerpc powerpc64 rios rios1 rios2 rs64 
rsc rsc1 titan
powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnuspe-gcc: error: unrecognized argument in option '-mtune=generic'
powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnuspe-gcc: note: valid arguments to '-mtune=' are: 401 403 405 405fp 440 440fp 464 464fp 476 476fp 505 601 
602 603 603e 604 604e 620 630 740 7400 7450 750 801 821 823 8540 8548 860 970 G3 G4 G5 a2 cell common e300c2 e300c3 e500mc 
e500mc64 ec603e native power power2 power3 power4 power5 power5+ power6 power6x power7 powerpc powerpc64 rios rios1 rios2 rs64 
rsc rsc1 titan
powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnuspe-gcc: error: unrecognized argument in option '-mtune=generic'
powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnuspe-gcc: note: valid arguments to '-mtune=' are: 401 403 405 405fp 440 440fp 464 464fp 476 476fp 505 601 
602 603 603e 604 604e 620 630 740 7400 7450 750 801 821 823 8540 8548 860 970 G3 G4 G5 a2 cell common e300c2 e300c3 e500mc 
e500mc64 ec603e native power power2 power3 power4 power5 power5+ power6 power6x power7 powerpc powerpc64 rios rios1 rios2 rs64 
rsc rsc1 titan
powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnuspe-gcc: error: unrecognized argument in option '-mtune=generic'
powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnuspe-gcc: note: valid arguments to '-mtune=' are: 401 403 405 405fp 440 440fp 464 464fp 476 476fp 505 601 
602 603 603e 604 604e 620 630 740 7400 7450 750 801 821 823 8540 8548 860 970 G3 G4 G5 a2 cell common e300c2 e300c3 e500mc 
e500mc64 ec603e native power power2 power3 power4 power5 power5+ power6 power6x power7 powerpc powerpc64 rios rios1 rios2 rs64 
rsc rsc1 titan
failure.
removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 266, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 258, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "/home/jenkins/Python-2.7.3/tmp/numpy-1.10.2rc2/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/jenkins/Python-2.7.3/tmp/numpy-1.10.2rc2/numpy/distutils/command/build.py", line 47, in run
    old_build.run(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/command/build.py", line 134, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 333, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/jenkins/Python-2.7.3/tmp/numpy-1.10.2rc2/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 153, in run
    self.build_sources()
  File "/home/jenkins/Python-2.7.3/tmp/numpy-1.10.2rc2/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 164, in build_sources
    self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
  File "/home/jenkins/Python-2.7.3/tmp/numpy-1.10.2rc2/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 299, in build_library_sources
    sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
  File "/home/jenkins/Python-2.7.3/tmp/numpy-1.10.2rc2/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 387, in generate_sources
    source = func(extension, build_dir)
  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 669, in get_mathlib_info
    raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
```

Comment: I installed distcrossutils and although the build -x option is not accepted it does appear to accept the compiler from the environment variables.

Comment: what also would help is a numpyconfig.h and config.h for busybox ppc environment